# Retrieve URL content and follow redirects

Tags: centos, url, wget

I want to visit an URL in CentOS and then automatically follow the redirects.
So, for example:

```
Visit http://domain.com
This will redirect my by a `header()` to another webpage, so automatically follow this redirect.
And this page will also redirect me.
Save the contents on the `landing` page.
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Wget does this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -L http://domain.com
```

> `-L/--location`
>                 (HTTP/HTTPS) If the server reports that the requested  page  has
>                 moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header
>                 and a 3XX response code), this option will make  curl  redo  the
>                 request  on the new place.

or `wget http://domain.com`